# Change background-color using jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change some css (background-color) dynamically within a file called alertPopup.js.

Basically I am using this in alertPopup.js (entire code):

```
(function (diagram) { $(document).ready(function () {

var diagramData = window.svgpublish.diagramData;
$.each(diagramData, function (shapeId, shapeData) {

    var props = shapeData.Props;
    if (!props)
        return;
    var $shape = $("#" + shapeId);



    // build options for popover: placement function, iframe url from properties
    var options1 = {    
        placement: function (context, source) {
            var position = $(source).position();
            if (position.right > 500)
                return "left";
            if (position.left < 500)
                return "right";
            if (position.top < 300)
                return "bottom";
            return "top";
        },
        trigger: "manual",
        container: "html",
        html: true,
        content: ''+
        '<span class="h5"><center><b> '+props.header+'</b></center></span>' +
        '<hr style="margin:5px"> ' +
        '<table border=0><tr><td><img src="'+props.Image+'"></img></td><td width=20px></td><td><span class="text-muted small"> ' + props.information1 + '</span></td></tr></table>',
        title: props.title
    };

    var options2 = {
        placement: function (context, source) {
            var position = $(source).position();
            if (position.right > 500)
                return "left";
            if (position.left < 500)
                return "right";
            if (position.top < 300)
                return "bottom";
            return "top";
        },
        trigger: "manual",
        container: "html",
        html: true,
        content: ''+
        '<span class="h5"><center><b> '+props.header+'</b></center></span>' +
        '<hr style="margin:5px">' +
        '<table border=0><tr><td><img src="'+props.Image+'"></img></td><td width=10px></td><td><span class="text-muted small"><ul><li> ' + props.information1 + '</li><li> ' + props.information2 + '</li></ul></span></td></tr></table>',
        title: props.title
    };

    var options3 = {    
        placement: function (context, source) {
            var position = $(source).position();
            if (position.right > 500)
                return "left";
            if (position.left < 500)
                return "right";
            if (position.top < 300)
                return "bottom";
            return "top";
        },
        trigger: "manual",
        container: "html",
        html: true,
        content: ''+
        '<span class="h5"><center><b> '+props.header+'</b></center></span>' +
        '<hr style="margin:5px">' +
        '<table border=0><tr><td><img src="'+props.Image+'"></img></td><td width=10px></td><td><span class="text-muted small"><ul><li> ' + props.information1 + '</li><li> ' + props.information2 + '</li><li> ' + props.information3 + '</li></ul></span></td></tr></table>',
        title: props.title
    };

    var options4 = {    
        placement: function (context, source) {
            var position = $(source).position();
            if (position.right > 500)
                return "left";
            if (position.left < 500)
                return "right";
            if (position.top < 300)
                return "bottom";
            return "top";
        },
        trigger: "manual",
        container: "html",
        html: true,
        content: ''+
        '<span class="h5"><center><b> '+props.header+'</b></center></span>' +
        '<hr style="margin:5px">' +
        '<table border=0><tr><td><img src="'+props.Image+'"></img></td><td width=10px></td><td><span class="text-muted small"><ul><li> ' + props.information1 + '</li><li> ' + props.information2 + '</li><li> ' + props.information3 + '</li><li> ' + props.information4 + '</li></ul></span></td></tr></table>',
        title: props.title
    };

    var options5 = {
        placement: function (context, source) {
            var position = $(source).position();
            if (position.right > 500)
                return "left";
            if (position.left < 500)
                return "right";
            if (position.top < 300)
                return "bottom";
            return "top";
        },
        trigger: "manual",
        container: "html",
        html: true,
        content: ''+
        '<span class="h5"><center><b> '+props.header+'</b></center></span>' +
        '<hr style="margin:5px">' +
        '<table border=0><tr><td><img src="'+props.Image+'"></img></td><td width=10px></td><td><span class="text-muted small"><ul><li> ' + props.information1 + '</li><li> ' + props.information2 + '</li><li> ' + props.information3 + '</li><li> ' + props.information4 + '</li><li> ' + props.information5 + '</li></ul></span></td></tr></table>',
        title: props.title
    };

    var options6 = {    
        placement: function (context, source) {
            var position = $(source).position();
            if (position.right > 500)
                return "left";
            if (position.left < 500)
                return "right";
            if (position.top < 300)
                return "bottom";
            return "top";
        },
        trigger: "manual",
        container: "html",
        html: true,
        content: ''+
        '<span class="h5"><center><b> '+props.header+'</b></center></span>' +
        '<hr style="margin:5px">' +
        '<table border=0><tr><td><img src="'+props.Image+'"></img></td><td width=10px></td><td><span class="text-muted small"><ul><li> ' + props.information1 + '</li><li> ' + props.information2 + '</li><li> ' + props.information3 + '</li><li> ' + props.information4 + '</li><li> ' + props.information5 + '</li><li> ' + props.information6 + '</li></ul></span></td></tr></table>',
        title: props.title
    };

var ImageOption = {
    placement: function (context, source) {
        var position = $(source).position();
        if (position.right > 500)
            return "left";
        if (position.left < 500)
            return "right";
        if (position.top < 300)
            return "bottom";
        return "top";
    },
    trigger: "manual",
    container: "html",
    html: true,
    content: '<img src="'+props.image_path+'"></img>'
};

        // create the popover for the shape  
if (props.infoItems == 1){  
        $shape.popover(options1);
};
if (props.infoItems == 2){  
        $shape.popover(options2);
};
if (props.infoItems == 3){  
        $shape.popover(options3);
};
if (props.infoItems == 4){  
        $shape.popover(options4);
};
if (props.infoItems == 5){  
        $shape.popover(options5);
};
if (props.infoItems == 6){  
        $shape.popover(options6);
};

if (props.eB_Image == "yes"){
        $shape.popover(ImageOption);
        $('.popover').css({backgroundColor:'yellow'});  
};

        // decorate the shape with "hand" cursor
        $shape.css("cursor", "pointer");

        // hide the popover hiding when clicked outside
        $('body').on('click', function (e) {
            $shape.popover('hide');
        });

        $shape.on('click', function (evt) { 
            evt.stopPropagation();
            $shape.popover('toggle');

        });

        $shape.on('mouseover', function () {
            $(this).attr('filter', 'url(#hover)');
        });

        $shape.on('mouseout', function () {
            $(this).removeAttr('filter');
        });

        $shape.tooltip({

        });
    });
});
 })(window.svgpublish);
```

The image is showing in the popup so I know that's working.

The CSS is this:

```
.popover {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1060;
display: none;
max-width: 450px;
padding: 1px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.42857143;
text-align: left;
text-align: start;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-break: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
word-wrap: normal;
white-space: normal;
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
line-break: auto}
```

But every time I refresh the HTML, the popups don't work any more.

This setup is complicated and was created with a Visio to SVG export tool but I have been able to adjust some of the code to get it to do what I want it to do.

For some reason though, this doesn't modify the background color attribute in the .popover css.

I can attach the full files (there are some JS files that are included but it looks like this is the one and the css file is the one). I can go in the css and change the attribute there and it works in the popup so I know that it is the right css and attribute.

Comment: what do you mean by *every time I refresh the HTML, the popups don't work any more.*, like they don't show anymore or the image and the background don't show anymore?

Comment: Yes, as soon as I put in "$('.popover').css({'background-color':'yellow'});" the popups don't work.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
var ImageOption = {
    $('.popover').css({'background-color','#f48035'});
    placement: function (context, source) {
        var position = $(source).position();
        if (position.right > 500)
            return "left";
        if (position.left < 500)
            return "right";
        if (position.top < 300)
            return "bottom";
        return "top";
    },
    trigger: "manual",
    container: "html",
    html: true,
    content: ''+
    '<img src="'+props.image_path+'"></img>'
};
```

will generate a

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

...JavaScript error because you're trying to run JavaScript while defining a variable. You need to place your jQuery command outside of the variable definition.

The second problem is with your jQuery `.css()` syntax. You either pass an object of properties to it, with respective values: `

```
.css({
   prop1:'propValue1', 
   prop2:'propValue2',
...})
```

or you pass two arguments: the property name first and property value second:

```
 .css('prop1','propValue1');
```

You have a mixture, which doesn't work: object with commas between the key and the value.

The code below will work, as long as you already have a variable called `props` with a property called `image_path` holding a valid path as value (which I assume you do, as you just posted a small snippet of a bit more code).

---

In short, you made two mistakes:
**a)** you placed your command inside a variable definition and
**b)** you had an error in your command's syntax.

```js
$('.popover').css({backgroundColor:'#f48035'});

var ImageOption = {
    placement: function (context, source) {
        var position = $(source).position();
        if (position.right > 500)
            return "left";
        if (position.left < 500)
            return "right";
        if (position.top < 300)
            return "bottom";
        return "top";
    },
    trigger: "manual",
    container: "html",
    html: true,
    content: '<img src="'+props.image_path+'"></img>'
};
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for this.

var props = shapeData.Props;

is were I define the data of the shape and the image_path is in the Props.

So the issue that I have is the changing of the background-color has to occur inside the var ImageOption since I want the background of the image to be different than the other options (non image).

Comment: In that case you need to post some more. Ideally it should be a [mcve]. I can't pinpoint errors in code you're not sharing.

Comment: @brentfraser Ref: *the background-color has to occur inside the var ImageOption*. In JavaScript ***nothing*** happens inside a variable definition. Never. Ever. It's illegal. It breaks. Defining a variable, regardless of how many functions you define as its properties, is a single instance in JavaScript. Keep in mind you are not running the functions defined in the variable. You are only defining them. You will run them later, after they were defined. I could point you to documentation but it will not make more sense to you than I do. Anyways, to run JS inside a variable definition is illegal.

Comment: @  Andrei Gheorghiu, I added the full JS here. Also @  Andrei Gheorghiu, I am not a programmer at all but have been asked to do this (tech writer with English degree) so I am doing my best without a lot of help @ work.

Comment: @brentfraser, well, in that case, the first sentence of the [tour] should spell it out. You're offtopic on [so], as it's only for programmers. Regardless, I'm willing to help. I don't have time to look over that wall of code now. I'll do it in a few hours, when i get home, if nobody else did it yet.

Comment: Thank you @Andrei Gheorghiu. I know this isn't the place for me but I am pretty much at a dead end unfortunately.

Comment: @brentfraser I took a quick look over it. I could explain you what's going on, when the code runs and what it does, and the programmer in you might benefit from it. However, it would take time and I'm not sure it's part of your current scope. In order to help you achieve what you actually want, I need two more things: **a)** the contents of `diagramData` object when `svgpublish` event is run on the `window`  object - you can get it from console if you place this line between 1st and 2nd line of what's now in question code: `console.log(window.svgpublish.diagramData)` and...

Comment: ... **b)** a way to get in contact, as helping you like this is borderline offtopic on SO. Point being: i'm only helping you. Your question doesn't benefit future users and that's the whole point of [so]. Reusable knowledge. It's not a free coding service. In order to get in touch you can use the contact form on my website, posted in my profile.

Comment: @ Andrei, thank you. I sent you a contact message using your form. I appreciate it very much.